# TextWatcher stop if count > 1

Tags: android

I'm trying to display / animate a TextView when user inputs a character (count > 1). But every time I change the text, the TextView animation repeats animating.

Is there any way that I can make it freeze if count > 1 and re-animate again (Fade out) if count < 0?

```
 fName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
         @Override
         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             if(count > 1) {
                 firstNameTV.startAnimation(in);
                 firstNameTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }

         }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
boolean flagAnimate=false;

    fName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
             @Override
             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                 if(count >= 1 && !flagAnimate) {
                     firstNameTV.startAnimation(in);
                     firstNameTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     flagAnimate= true;
                 } else if(count == 0){
                     firstNameTV.startAnimation(out);
                     firstNameTV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                     flagAnimate= false;
                        }

             }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged (Editable s){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

        });
```

This code solve your problem. :)

Comment: congratulation. if my answer is useful for you, please give me vote up. thanks